# Prove/Disprove linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Consider following question:

Prove/Disprove:

> 1.If vectors {a,b,c} and {d,e} are  linearly independent then {a,b,c,d,e} are linearly independent.
>
> 2.If vectors {a,b,c,d,e} are  linearly independent then vectors {d,e} are linearly independent.
>
> 3.If vectors {a,b,c,d,e} are  linearly independent then vectors {d,e,f} are linearly independent.

For Q2:  I think that this is true beacuse if you take Ax=0 then you can simplify it into uppertriangular form and then {d,e} must be linearly independent.Then vectors {d,e} are linearly independent.

For Q1,Q3:I am not sure how to deal with it.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1) is false: Take $d=a,e=b$. 2) is  true by definition of linear independence. What is f) in 3)?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  "f" is other vector in set {d,e,f}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1)

The vectors d or e can be equal to any of the vector in {a,b,c}. That is counter example.

Q2)

You are right!

Q3)

It is the same as Q1. The vector f can depend on any of the vectors  d and e.